# How do I start and what tools should I use to develop websites with amazing animations?

Tags: user-interface, animation, css-animations

I'm a frontend developer but so far I only developed websites without great animations, only few CSS animations and no such great or outstanding transition effects between pages.

I use frameworks like Angular and Vue (no React for now) and am aware of libraries like GSAP.

Right now I'm still wondering how I can achive a result like the following websites:

https://octoplus.ch/it

https://monza.ferrari.com/it-it/monza-sp2 (look at the amount of details of this one!)

... but don't know where to start from, which tools to use to have such great animations and a fluid user experience. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Most of what you see on those sites are created by libraries that can manipulate the html5 `<canvas>` element.

Libraries that handle `<canvas>`:

- Three.js
- Babylon.js
- D3.js

For example, what I would do to create something like https://octoplus.ch/it is to create a `Three.js` based website. The loading you see at the start is when `Three.js` loads assets from the website, you can't have a loader without something to load. After that all you're seeing is a `Three.js` application with a scene and animations. Note that they might not be using `Three.js`, but that's how I'd make it since I'm familiar with it. They use something similar to it.

I would use `Nuxt.js` or `Vue` for handling the initial website stuff, like the loading part, binding the loading value to a variable with Vue.

So to summarize what I'd recommend for you is a Nuxt.js application that uses either Three.js, Babylon.js or D3.js for the fancy graphics.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions Simon! :)